# Change in kinetic energy of a charge is zero

Tags: electrostatics

If i move positive test charge from infinity to a point in the electric field of positive charge untill it reaches certain point And my external work made the change in kinetic energy zero does that mean the charge will stay stationary at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not. If there is a nonzero net electric field at that point, then the charge will begin to accelerate.

Comment: Do you mean it stops And starts accelerating

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey Was it moving before? If you moved the charge from infinity to this point in such a way that the change in kinetic energy is zero, then it had the same kinetic energy now as it did before you moved it. If it had nonzero kinetic energy before you moved it, then it will have nonzero kinetic energy (and thus be moving) after you move it, too.

Comment: I move it from rest

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey Then, if you move it such that the change in kinetic energy is zero, it will be at rest for the infinitesimal moment when you finish moving it. After that, it will move, because there is a net force on it.